# Showing $x=A^\dagger b$ is the unique minimum norm solution of $\Vert A_{m\times n}x_n - b_m \Vert$

Tags: linear-algebra, least-squares

Consider the **least squares** problem.

" Find **minimizer** $x \in \mathbb{C}^n$ :  $\Vert A_{m\times n}x_n - b_m \Vert$"

---

### Problem

> Assume $\Vert Ax - b \Vert_2 = \Vert A A^\dagger b - b\Vert_2 $
>
> **Show** : $\Vert x \Vert_2 > \Vert A^\dagger b \Vert$, if $\exists x \neq A^\dagger b$

where $A^\dagger$ denotes [Moore-Penrose inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse) of $A$.

---

### Try

It is not difficult to show

$$
\Vert Ax - b \Vert_2 \ge \Vert A A^\dagger b -b \Vert_2
$$

because

$$
\begin{aligned}
\Vert Ax - b \Vert_2^2 = \Vert A A^\dagger b -b  \Vert_2^2 + \Vert Ax - A A^\dagger b\Vert_2^2 + c + \bar{c}
\end{aligned}
$$

where $c = (Ax - A A^\dagger b)^\ast(Ax - A A^\dagger b) = x^\ast A^\ast A A^\dagger b - x^\ast A^\ast b - b^\ast (A A^\dagger)^2 b + b^\ast (A A^\dagger) b = 0$

thus we get

$$
\Vert Ax - b\Vert_2^2 \ge \Vert A A^\dagger b -b \Vert_2^2
$$

---

Now, I would like to show that

$$
\Vert x \Vert_2^2 = \Vert A A^\dagger \Vert_2^2 + \Vert x - A^\dagger b \Vert_2^2
$$

So I wrote:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\Vert x \Vert_2^2 &= \Vert A^\dagger b + x - A^\dagger \Vert_2^2 \\
&= \Vert A^\dagger b \Vert_2^2 + \Vert x - A^\dagger b \Vert_2^2 + c + \bar{c}
\end{aligned}
$$

where $c = b^\ast (A^\dagger)^\ast (x - A^\dagger b)$.

---

**But I'm stuck at showing** $c = 0$

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure I have answered this kind of question some years ago, but I cannot find the answer now.

It is the easiest to prove that $c=0$ (step 4 below) if you use the explicit form of the solution $x$ (all solutions to the LS problem).

The steps:

1. All LS solutions are the solutions to the normal equation $A^*Ax=A^*b$.
2. [All solutions are given](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse#Obtaining_all_solutions_of_a_linear_system) by the formula 
   $$
   x=(A^*A)^+A^*b+(I-(A^*A)^+A^*A)w.
   $$
3. Use [the property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse#Reduction_to_Hermitian_case) $A^+=(A^*A)^+A^*$ to rewrite
   $$
   x=A^+b+(I-A^+A)w.
   $$
4. Prove that $A^+b\ \bot\ (I-A^+A)w$ e.g. by
   $$
   (I-A^+A)^*A^+=[(A^+A)^*=A^+A]=(I-A^+A)A^+=A^+-A^+AA^+=0.
   $$